# GitLab not interacting with Gitolite

Tags: git, debian, gitolite, gitlab

I got GitLab installed and configured. I added my public key to my account and then added a project. Unfortunately, the project does not appear to exist in Gitolite, nor do my keys appear to have been added (not in .gitolite/keydir or .ssh/authorized_keys)

GitLab doesn't complain, the project is created fine. Permissions are correct, according to gitlab:app:status, but it says the post_receive file is missing for the project.. which is unsurprising since there is no project in /home/git/repositories

```
gitlab@server:~$ bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production
Starting diagnostics
config/database.yml............exists
config/gitlab.yml............exists
/home/git/repositories/............exists
/home/git/repositories/ is writable?............YES
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Can clone gitolite-admin?............YES
UMASK for .gitolite.rc is 0007? ............YES
/home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive exists? ............YES
Validating projects repositories:
Herp.....post-receive file missing
rake aborted!
unexpected return

Tasks: TOP => gitlab:app:status
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

EDIT: The gitolite-admin repo does exist. I'm able to both clone the gitolite-admin repo and write in that directory:

```
gitlab@server:~$ git clone git@localhost:gitolite-admin.git /tmp/gitolite-admin
Cloning into '/tmp/gitolite-admin'...
remote: Counting objects: 6, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), 751 bytes, done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

gitlab@server:~$ mkdir /home/git/repositories/test
gitlab@server:~$ touch /home/git/repositories/test/asdf
```

I'm at a loss and GitLab is unusable as a result. What do I do? I'm not sure where to even start looking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No project in `/home/git/repositories`: is there at least the gitolite-admin repo?

Comment: @VonC Yes, the gitolite-admin repo exists. I'm able to both clone the gitolite-admin repo and write in that directory

Comment: Ok, I am in the process of installing GitLab (latest from `master`: 3.0.3) myself (on a RedHat box), with latest from Gitolite (V3.x). I will test and report.

Comment: @VonC Okay, thanks. I'll be awake for the next several hours, please let me know what happens

Comment: To anyone who comes here from Google: Just use Gitorious instead. You won't regret it. GitLab was a massive waste of time

Comment: I don't have that choice at work. I will finish my installation Monday.

Comment: Agree with Salis. GitLab was the biggest maintenance hog in my entire gentoo build, the installation is from slackware days and good luck fixing it if something breaks. If you're a single developer like me and github.com plans are too pricey for your amount of repos - just use bitbucket, don't waste your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the root of this problem was that commits to the gitolite-admin repos were being rejected:

```
2012-11-05.18:54:07     gitlab  127.0.0.1       git-receive-pack 'gitolite-admin'
2012-11-05.18:54:07     gitlab  127.0.0.1       Die generated at line 251 in /home/git/bin/gl-compile-conf : <<newline>>                ***** ABORTING *****<<newline>>        git config core.sharedRepository not allowed<<newline>>check GL_GITCONFIG_KEYS in the rc file for how to allow it<<newline>> <<newline>>
```

When I checked if `/home/git/.gitolite.rc` for `GL_GITCONFIG_KEYS` I found out that the variable had the value empty string. I had to change it manually:

```
$GL_GITCONFIG_KEYS = ".*";
```

(I extrapolated from the migration sed line as specified in [issue 1769](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1769) - I think the given sed line is broken)

For gitolite v3 you might need to set this variable instead

```
$GIT_CONFIG_KEYS = '.*';
```

Adding this variable fixed the issue for me.

Edit: Alternative problem and solution suggested by japgolly is that the install instructions forget a step:

```
sudo -u gitlab git config --global user.name Gitlab
sudo -u gitlab git config --global user.email gitlab@localhost
```

which also causes commits to gitolite-admin to fail (silently)